# Print array objects on each line

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm printing an array out through this code:

```
HomePlayersLabel.text = [HomePlayersString componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

This works fine, but it prints the array on the same line. i've tried by using \n, but the label do not fit printing the array on each line.

How can i autosize the label, so all objects in array will be printed on next line?

i've found lots of posts, but all are deprecated on IOS 6.0

Comment: Sounds like this is an AutoLayout question...

Comment: `label.numberOfLines = 0;` and it will adjust itself. Might need to change its frame to something reasonably high.

Comment: Oh, and ***please please please*** don't call it `HomePlayersLabel`, with an upper-case initial. Sounds like a class. Call it `homePlayersLabel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.text = [playersArray componentsJointByString:@"\n"];
```

And please heed the advice:

1. Variables should be `camelCase` with non-uppercase initial. Capitalised expressions are used as class names by convention. (See the wrong colouring of your code above.)
2. Variables should be named after what they are. You should not describe an array as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `@" "` with `@"\n"` so each value is separated by a newline. Then be sure your label has its `numberOfLines` set to `0` and also the height of the label is tall enough to show all of the lines. Using `sizeToFit` will help with that.